# Which languages compile to CIL / MSIL

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, cil, managed-code

Most of the lists I have seen comprise:

- C#
- VB.Net
- Other .NET language

What languages fall into the "Other" category?

I've come across:

- Delphi
- C++
- Cobol.Net
- Chrome

I'm sure there must be others?

Comment: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_languages">Here's a large list.</a>

Comment: Check these lists of CLI-based languages: - [dotNetPowered Language List](http://www.dotnetpowered.com/languages.aspx) - [List of CLI languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_languages) They are pretty comprehensive, I didn't even know about [lolcode-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/lolcode-dot-net/)
!